# Null pointer exception while starting a process outside Alfresco Activiti

Tags: java, alfresco, activiti

I am using Alfresco Activiti and want to initiate a task outside of it. I have written a standalone java program to do this (i.e my java program creates a task in alfresco activiti on execution).

```
    TaskService taskService=processEngine.getTaskService();
    Task task=taskService.createTaskQuery().taskAssignee("USER MAYA SHARMA").singleResult();

    System.out.println(task.getName());
```

The program runs fine as long as my `taskAssignee` is $INITIATOR, but when I change my `taskAssignee` to a real user in alfresco activiti, it throws a null pointer exception.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException at TestingABC.main(TestingABC.java:34)
```

Comment: Which line is "34"? Where are you getting the exception?

Comment: You need to add full exception details. The way you are passing user is wrong

Comment: Hi Toubou !! Line no 34 is System.out.println(task.getName());. What is correcy way of passing user name's in Alfresco Activiti ?

Answer (score 0):

`NullPointerException` occurs when you try to call a method on a `null` Object. For example:

```
String aNullString = null;
aNullString.indexOf("");
```

will give a `NullPointerException` because `aNullString` is `null`, which does not have any methods.

---

If your error is occurring on the **first** line you posted, then that means `processEngine` is `null`.

If the error is thrown on the **second** line, then either:

1. `taskService`
2. `taskService.singleResult`

is `null`

If the error is thrown on the **third** line, then `task` is `null`.

> Please edit your post so that I know which line you posted is throwing the error so I can give a more detailed response.

Comment: Hi AMACB, Thanks for your reply. The null pointer occurs at System.out.println(task.getName()); I guess the taskService.singleResult is causing the nullpointer exception. I am sure the way I am passing the error is wrong. Please help

Comment: Hmm, so somehow either: `task` is `null`; or, `.getName()` has a bug in it. Try `System.out.println(task);`

Comment: I am able to see the name of the task when I assign the task to "$INITIATOR", but I get a null pointer exception when I assign the task to some other assignee(e.g ABC ABC). I am probably not assigning the user properly. What is the proper way of assigning users ? I am using Alfresco Activiti for creating the process and Eclipse IDE for creating the java program(which initiates the task outside of activiti).